# How to make a file only readable after a certain date?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to send someone a file (a .mov video to be precise) but I only want them to be able to open the file after a certain date.

Here are my requirements:

1. I know the client uses a version OSX which has bash (and maybe
   python)
2. I can't assume other person will have any other programs
3. I can't use system time since its easy to change, I will need to use a time server

Here is my plan:

1. Encrypt the file using OpenSSL in terminal with a password
2. Write a script to check date from a time server (python or bash) and decrypt the file if the pre-determined date has bean reached.
3. Use SHC to convert to script to binary in order make the code and password unreadable
4. Send both files together instructing the user to run the binary script

(SHC is a program that converts any script to binary from: https://github.com/neurobin/shc)

I have no idea how to check a time server using bash or python (or even if this is possible)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on [security.se]: [Ensure that a file can only be decrypted after a specific date](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/89094/8715)

Comment: Why not just withhold the decryption key until the desired day?

Comment: @jwodder from the answer that you have posted: "Of course this does not guarantee a release at a specific date; rather, it guarantees a minimum effort to unlock the puzzle."

Comment: @chepner where is the joy of programming in there:)

Comment: @tTIKA: So?  The point of that answer is that you *can't* enforce readability only after a certain date.

Comment: @jwodder of course its possible somehow, I am just trying to figure out how

Comment: Whatever response your server sends to *verify* that the correct date and time has been reached can just send the *key* instead.

Comment: Maybe make a password-encrypted, self-extracting archive with 7zip (which you can install on your Mac with **homebrew**, and the lucky, hopefully patient, recipient doesn't need) and send it to them followed by the password on the appropriate day. Or just tell them to wait and send a plain file on the day.

Answer (score 3):

This is physically impossible unless you use a server that you control to give them the decryption key at the right time. If you give them the key before that, you can't prevent them from extracting the key from said script.

The easiest way to do this to send them the file with a decryption script ahead of time. When they want to watch the movie, they can run the script. The decryption script then makes a request from your server. If and only if the time is past your specified point, the server responds with the decryption key.

Alternatively, send them a download link that is only active after the specified time.

Comment: This is a valid problem but this wont be sent to anyone who has the technical knowhow of figuring out the password from the script. (since I will only send the binary version of the script created by SHC)

Comment: @tTIKA: Security through obscurity... That's worked well in the past.

Comment: @tTIKA: I highly suggest that you don't underestimate a bored person's ability to use Google. What you're suggesting is trivial, and I know plenty of high school kids who could do it.

Comment: I cant agree more, but this is the best way I came up with:( do you know a better way?

Comment: @tTIKA: My answer is the only way to go about doing something like this. Anything else is magic. Programmers can do impressive things, sure, but contrary to what most of the population seems to believe about encryption, we are not wizards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not impossible, I've done it. Ok a third secure third party time server is involved but that's it. You can create an encrypted file/message/document that will only be decrypted and readable on a date of your choice. You could even possibly add to an encrypted document.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).